# ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 244: Can't create table './intranet2/dept.frm' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I dumped a DB from the production:

mysqldump -u user_name -p intranet2 > intranet2.sql

into the development server:

mysql -u user_name -p intranet2 < intranet2.sql

and I get this:

ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 244: Can't create table './intranet2/dept.frm' (errno: 150)

I tried to put this in the beginning of the sql file:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

but I still getting the same message. mysqldump should be able to recreate a database otherwise who can I trust that my backup?

Comment: I removed two foreign key from Dept table and it worked. But, if I use 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;' why the b----y MySql was applying foregn constraints? My opinion is still the mysqldump is quite unreliable.

Comment: I put my solution here: http://riccardotacconi.blogspot.com/2009/11/error-1005-hy000-at-line-cant-create.html

Answer (score 3):

Checks if the engine is InnoDB.

In this case you could try to put these lines at the beginning of the dump

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
```

and these end

```
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
```

good luck

Comment: I ran into this error with a mysqldump --all-database file which I'd edited to extra a single database from the dump and where I'd hacked off the metainfo at the beginning of the database. When I restored it from another, single, dump file it was fine.

Comment: I am still facing this issue dispute having these lines.  even /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES' */; does not help

Comment: You must include all lines, not only the last, and run your script as a single transaction.